# How to take screenshot in iOS 9 with private API in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, iphone-privateapi

I want to take screenshot in background with private API in iOS 9 jailbroken iPhone. The old program from iOS 8 can not work with iOS 9.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess this a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360827/get-screenshot-of-current-screen-in-ios-swift-for-sharing/43361428#43361428

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu It looks like can only work for the app self as the active app...? I want to take screenshot in background for other apps and it will running in tweak.